# Select MIN from VARCHAR (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a varcher column named "prices" where prices are stored in the European format, like:

```
10,13
40,34
28,23
```

(I know that it would be better to choose another format instead of varchar, but I have reasons for it)

I want now to select the cheapest price.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
    MIN(prices)
FROM
    rates
```

It's not working. Any "dirty" trick for me? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql query for selecting min/max values in a varchar field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512946/mysql-query-for-selecting-min-max-values-in-a-varchar-field)

Comment: Number formats are better provided in the presentation layer and not in the database

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work.  But if the prices have different lengths, then this might work:

```
select price
from rates
order by length(price), price;
limit 1;
```

Comment: it is highly unlikely that the prices will be of same length

Comment: @trillion . . . That is what this answer addresses.